# How do we check in pharo if an element already exist in a set

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, pharo-5

Say I have a function that continually add a random number to a collection after each refresh.

```html
Myfunction
|list length data |

z := Set new.
x := 8.
data:= received data after each refresh.
length := data size.
1 to: length do:[:k | list := data at: k.
    list < x
    "How to check if this data already exist and not add"
        ifTrue:[z add: list]
```

How can I check in Pharo if a number already exists and if so it should not add it again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sets and other basic collections are part of common Smalltalk. You should have a look at the Smalltalk documentation (*e.g.*, the [Smalltalk bluebook](http://stephane.ducasse.free.fr/FreeBooks/BlueBook/Bluebook.pdf)), particularly the references for each of the data types you are attempting to use as well as other related ones.

If you read the documentation for `Set` you'll find a message `#includes:` which will return true if the argument is in the set, and return false if it isn't. That would look like:

```
(z includes: list) ifTrue: [ z add: list ]
```

But, a `Set` by definition contains unique elements. Therefore, if you attempt to add an element that's already in the set, Smalltalk will not add it again and not give you an error if you attempt to do so. So you don't need to check to see if the set already includes `list`. You can just add it.

Then you are doing your data traversal the long, hard way. You don't need to get the length then loop on an index from 1 to that length. I assume your data is some kind of Smalltalk *Collection*, so you can just use the  `#do:` message. The `#do:` message allows you to iterate a block over each element of the collection:

```
data do: [ :each | each < x ifTrue: [ z add: each ] ]
```

This replaces everything you have shown starting at `length := ...`.

Comment: That's clearly the best explanation compared to the documentation. Thank you @lurker

Comment: @ludo I'm glad it helped. One thing about the documentation is that it will list for your all of the messages available for the various classes. So that's always a good launching point. I agree that the documentation can be terse with its explanations. If you find my answer above acceptable, if you could be so kind as to accept it by clicking the check mark next to it, I'd be much obliged.

Comment: @lurker Can you point us to a link to the documentation for the Pharo standard library?  Thanks.

Comment: @GregBuchholz I did not refer to "Pharo standard library" documentation. I mentioned "Smalltalk documentation". If, for example, you look at the [Smalltalk Bluebook](http://stephane.ducasse.free.fr/FreeBooks/BlueBook/Bluebook.pdf), sets and other collections are described there and `includes:` is one of the standard messages for a collection. Pharo, GNU smalltalk, VA Smalltalk, have their own deviations from the original standard, but follow it pretty closely for the common collections.